# How do I use checkboxes in an IF-THEN statement in Excel VBA 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to use the value of checkboxes for an IF-THEN statement. Based on what the user checks, the way I have to calculate things changes. However, I can't figure out how to use the checkbox values, or how to detect them. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Range("E1:F7,A1:A4,B1:B4,C1:C3").Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1") = "Time"
    Range("B1") = "Specimen Shape"
    Range("C1") = "Data Type"
    Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
    Range("E1") = "Owner"
    Range("E2") = "Experiment Date"
    Range("E3") = "Specimen ID"
    Range("E4") = "Contaminant"
    Range("E5") = "Leachant"
    Range("E6") = "Temperature"
    Range("E7") = "Regression Title"
    Range("E1:E7").Font.Bold = True
    Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.EntireColumn.Autofit
    'Formatting Column A
    Columns("A").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 9.71
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(4, 14.5, 72, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Days"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(4, 30.5, 73.5, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Hours"
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(4, 45.75, 52.5, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Minutes"
    'Formatting Column B
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(58, 14.5, 72, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Cylinder"
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(58, 30.5, 73.5, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Wafer"
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(58, 45.75, 52.5, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Irregular"
    'Formatting Column C
    Columns("C").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 12.71
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(140.5, 14.5, 72, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Incremental"
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(140.5, 30.5, 72, 17.25).Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Cumulative"
    Columns("F").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 60
    Range("A1:C1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("F1").Select
    Dim btn As Button
    Dim rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range("A9:C9")
            Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        With btn
            .Caption = "After making your selections above, click this button to continue."
            .AutoSize = True
            .OnAction = "DataInput"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

What I want it to do, just as a test, is if the "Time" checkbox is checked, and then the button is pressed to continue, I want it to say something like "YAY", using an IF-THEN statement. If the "Time" checkbox is not checked and you press continue, I'd like it to say "AWW...".

This is what I tried to make that happen, and it isn't working.

```
Sub DataInput()
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box 1")).Value = True Then
    MsgBox ("Yay")
    Else: MsgBox ("Aww")
    End If
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True Then
```

I believe Tim is right. You have a Form Control. For that you have to use this

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
```

Comment: I got an error, "Unable to get the OLEObjects property of the Worksheet class". ?

Comment: 1) Did you replace "Sheet1" with the relevant sheet name? 2) Did you replace "CheckBox1" with the relevant Checkbox name?

Comment: Yes, it still didn't work :\

I just spaced out "Checkbox1", since when I recorded a macro and deleted that checkbox, the macro was: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Check Box 1")).Select`

Comment: You probably have to change the name in Siddharth's response to "Check Box 1" to match what your shape is called

Comment: That will work for an ActiveX checkbox, but I'm not sure it works for a Forms checkbox

Comment: It worked!!! How was I supposed to figure that out on my own :P Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this....

```
Dim cbTime

Set cbTime = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(100, 100, 50, 15)
With cbTime
    .Name = "cbTime"
    .Characters.Text = "Time"
End With

If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbTime").Value = 1 Then 'or just cbTime.Value
    'checked
Else
    'unchecked
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

A checkbox has a linked cell, which contains the True/False representing the state of the checkbox. It is much easier to reference this cell's value than the value of the embedded object which is the checkbox.

Manually: Right click on the checkbox, choose Format, click in the Linked Cell box, and select the cell to contain the checkbox value.

In code:

```
Set cbTime = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(100, 100, 50, 15)
With cbTime
    .Value = xlOff ' = unchecked  xlOn = checked
    .LinkedCell = "$A$1"
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub Datainput()
'Checkbox values are 0 (false), 1 (true), 2 (changed or grey)
    If activesheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").value = 1 then
        Msgbox ("Yay")
        Else: Msgbox("Aww")
    End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I could access the checkbox directly using `Worksheets("SheetName").CB_Checkboxname.value`
directly without relating to additional objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in VBA macro code for an ActiveX checkbox control you use

If (ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = True)

and for a Form checkbox control you use

If (ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1)