# Get reference to Forms checkbox in VBA event handler

Tags: vba, excel, office-2010

I have some Forms Checkboxes in Excel 2010. I need to perform some common code when they are clicked. To do this, I'd like to pass a reference to the Checkbox, but so far I'm only able to get it typed as a shape.

To preempt the question, yes, they need to be Form Checkboxes and not ActiveX Checkboxes.

I'm a novice with VBA, so any help is appreciated.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    'I really want this reference to be a Checkbox, not a Shape
    Dim shape As Shape
    Set shape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1")            

    DoSomething(shape)
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(MSForms.CheckBox)
    'I need the reference to be a checkbox as I need to check 
    'whether it's checked or not here
End Sub
```

Comment: Worksheet's checkboxes from Form category are of Shape type. You can't *cast* them to a CheckBox type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to Siddharth's but adds the `ControlFormat` property of the `Shape`. `ControlFormat` gets you the Intellisense for the `CheckBox`, in this case `Value`:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim chk As Shape

Set chk = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
With chk.ControlFormat
    If .Value = True Then
        MsgBox "true"
    Else
        MsgBox "false"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991308/how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-an-if-then-statement-in-excel-vba-2010

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I looked at the link. What does your comment mean?

Comment: I already upvoted your answer :) I posted the above comment after I posted it in the comments of my answer. Just wanted to let you know that it was already covered :)

Answer (score 4):

In such a scenario, don't have different click event for all checkboxes. Have just one. And use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the ckeckbox which called it. Pass that as a `String` to the relevant sub and then work with it.

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub CheckBoxMain_Click()
    Dim sName As String

    sName = Application.Caller

    DoSomething (sName)
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(sCheck As String)
    Dim shp As shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(sCheck)

    With shp
        '~~> Do something
    End With
End Sub
```

You could also combine the two into one as well and link it with all checkboxes.

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Dim shp As shape

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    With shp
        '~~> Do something
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My understanding was that Excel did not allow you to have a common event handler for more than one control. Is that not true? Believe me, I'd like nothing more. Still, this doesn't address my problem. I need the shape typed as a Checkbox with a Value property, in your code it's still typed as a Shape.

Comment: @MgSam: That is because you said it's a Form Control and not an ActiveX control? For form controls you can use one sub

Comment: Ahh, thanks. That's very helpful. Do you know how I could check it's Value property to see if it's checked or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991308/how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-an-if-then-statement-in-excel-vba-2010