# Release a file from excel generated by VBA to allow for moving of file

Tags: vba, excel

I am using some code in my excel document to open images, rotate them as appropriate and then save them to a temp folder (see [How do I rotate a saved image with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001667/rotate-a-saved-image-with-vba)).
I am now trying to rename these generated images within the same folder using `Name... as...`, however this throws up an error, saying that the image is still in use by Excel ("File/Path access error" in VBA - it tells me its in use by excel when renaming it in an explorer window though)

Is there any way to "throw this out" of Excel using VBA before this stage? I did try `Set p = Nothing` (with p coming from `Set p = .Pictures.Insert(Filepath)`) but this still gives an error. The sheet that the new image is created from is deleted after it is saved to the temp folder so it does not exist on the sheet any more either. Once I fully close excel, I can rename the file again.

Comment: Are you referring to renaming the the `NewPath` image

Comment: Yes, it will be renaming the `NewPath` images to something else within the same folder (and then eventually moving that folder from temp to its permanent location)

Comment: Why not copy the file from temp to that permanent folder instead of renaming and then moving the folder? You can later use the Kill Command to delete that file from the temp folder. `OR` instead of the temp folder use the actual folder in the code and set the `NewPath` in the code accordingly?

Comment: Am looking into alternatives as well. Thinking it may be just as easy to copy the entire newpath folder to another temp folder and then work from those ones (as editing the copies wont have the restrictions). Although would still like to know if this is possible

Comment: lol, I beat you to it :) See my prev comment.

Comment: Would rather not use the actual folder until its done (as its a server location and can be slow). Plus there are files in the actual folder that need to be renamed after (as sometimes there are name clashes which is why its safest to do it locally in a temp environment first and have the code deal with these right before moving it all to its proper location)

Comment: Then use the first option `copy the file from temp to that permanent folder instead of renaming and then moving the folder`

Answer (score 0):

The "solution" I ended up with was to copy folder `C:\Temp\a\` to `C:\Temp\b\` and make the changes from there before copying to `\\my\actual\location`

This works OK as a decent workaround for this instance,  but by no means a 100% complete answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

YOUR CODE HERE.....

CLOSE

'by add "close" at the ending of your line before conducting the next action