# How to rotate an image in excel using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, image

Hi I'm trying to rotate an image in excel using vba, I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Image1.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 90

End Sub
```

but I don't get the expect results.

This is how I pick the image:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .ButtonName = "Inserisci"
    .Title = "Selezionare foto"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
    .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
    .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
    .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
    .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
    .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

    If .Show = -1 Then

       Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom

       Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(.SelectedItems(1))

    Else
        MsgBox ("Cancelled.")
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Image1 is a image in a user form.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What is `Image1`?

Comment: Can you paste screenshots of how you want to see your images ?

Comment: "I don't get the expect results". What result do you get?

Comment: @FunThomas I have updated the code

Comment: So you don't want to rotate an image on a sheet, but on a user form? There is no build in function for that. Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002905/7599798 for a work around function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a saved image with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001667/rotate-a-saved-image-with-vba)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply remove the `ShapeRange` part of it, and you should be set. That depends on how you declared the image object though.
Here's an example:

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Img As Shape
Set Sh = ActiveSheet
Set Img = Sh.Shapes(1)
Img.IncrementRotation 90
```