# Unchecked checkbox value does not result in zero value

Tags: excel, if-statement, checkbox, vba

In Excel 2010, VBA, when the checkbox is unchecked, the code should not run.  However it is running when the checkbox is unchecked.  What am I missing?

EDIT:  The unchecked checkbox results in "-4146" in the Immediate window.  So I changed the `IF` condition to `<> 1`.   Isn't an unchecked checkbox supposed to be equal to zero?

EDIT 2:  I forgot to mention, this is a FORM CONTROL checkbox.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'delete range on the active row from column I to column M and shift up
'I=9, M = 13
Dim delAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Const WS_Range As String = "I:M"

'Checks to see if user wants macro turned on
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo ws_exit
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Check to see if user is in applicable range for macro to run
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Me.Range(WS_Range)) Is Nothing Then

'Ask user to confirm running macro
With Target
aR = ActiveCell.Row
delAnswer = MsgBox("Delete I" & aR & ":M" & aR & "?", vbYesNo)

'Macro - deletes range of cells on the active row
If delAnswer = vbYes Then
Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Resize(, 5).Delete Shift:=xlUp

Else: GoTo ws_exit
End If
End With
End If

ws_exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
'Debug.Print Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
'Debug.Print "ar is " & aR
End Sub
```

Comment: How about this: `If Me.CheckBox4.Value = 0 Then` ... but make sure you have the correct name of the checkbox object (see in the Properties box). In other words, it's Caption **Check Box 4** may be different then it's *object name*.

Comment: When I try this `Me.Checkbox4.Value, I receive error "Method or data member not found."

Comment: Yes, please see my answer. I posted that comment before you edited your post to note it was a form control.

Comment: The values for a Form checkbox are `xlOn`, `xlMixed` or `xlOff`

Answer (score 0):

I would determine if the form checkbox is not checked in the following manner:

```
If Not ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

    MsgBox ("unchecked")

End If
```

I referred to the following answer on how to detect checked value for Form or ActiveX controls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11991419/5692872

Comment: this is not an acceptable answer on SO. If you want to link to a previous question, put that in the comments of the OP. (Then delete this as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change

`If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value = 0`

To

`If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value = -4146`

-4146 is the numerical equivalent to an unchecked Form Control check box. To test if the check box is indeed checked, use `= 1` instead of `= -4146`

Answer (score 0):

I found these both work by changing:
`If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value = 0`
to:
`If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value <> 1`
or
`If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 4").ControlFormat.Value = xloff`