# 'Object Required' Error when trying to refer to CheckBox in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code in excel vba.

I want to change the color of the user selected cell when the checkbox is checked.

I have already written this code but it gives the 'object required' error on the line marked.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()    
Dim xRng As Range    
Set xRng = Selection

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 'This is the error    
    xRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen    
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = False Then    
    xRng.Interior.Color = xlNone    
End If

End Sub
```

Please help me on how to debug this error.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11991419/4650297) help?  Or perhaps [this one](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/45786-if-clause-visual-basic-applications-look-checkbox-if-its-checked-not.html)?

Comment: Is your checkbox on a worksheet or a form? Is it an ActiveX control or a Form control if it's on a worksheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne: I am having trouble opening the link!!!

Comment: @JiminyCricket A lot of people don't know the difference and thus are unaware which one they implemented. Hence, I always try to include the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20

Comment: @JiminyCricket: My checkbox is on the worksheet. And it is Form Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that this is what you want:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim xRng As Range
Set xRng = Selection

If Worksheets("Sheet2").CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 1 Then
    xRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
    xRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If

End Sub
```

<sub>Don't forget to adjust the names `Sheet2` and `Check Box 1` to the actual names in your file.</sub>

Here is a step-by-step video solution:

[image]

Comment: This code gives me another error!
`Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Set xRng = Selection
If Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("Checkbox1").Value = 1 Then 'Here is the error Allication-defined or object-defined error
xRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
xRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If
End Sub`

Comment: Sorry for the messy presentation. I just clicked enter so it got posted. I hope you can understand!

Comment: Did you change `Sheet2` and `Check Box 1` according to the actual names you have in your Excel file?

Comment: Yes I did change it the respective names I am using!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am able to run the code now! I was using the edited text name as my checkbox name in the code and not its original name!

Comment: @Pooja : In order : **Take the [tour] (click it)**, Accept and upvote this awesome answer and go back to your profile to do the same on helpful answers on your previous questions! ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default the code for such a control is placed in a regular module,
 so you'll have to specify the sheet (change `Sheet's name`) on which your control is placed :

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()    
Dim xRng As Range
Set xRng = Selection

If  ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet's name").Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    xRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
    xRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If

End Sub
```

---

If you place that code in the sheet's module where the checkbox is,
the easiest way to fix this would be to try adding `Me`:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()    
Dim xRng As Range
Set xRng = Selection

If Me.Shapes("Check Box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
    xRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
    xRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to use this code, it gives me 'method or data member not found' error on the very first line!

Comment: @Pooja : Do you mean `Sub CheckBox1_Click()` or `If Me.CheckBox1.Value `?

Comment: I meant `Sub CheckBox1_Click()` This is where it gives the error 'method or data member not found'

Comment: @Pooja : My bad, I thought that by default the code of the form would be place in the sheet's module, but it isn't! I'll edit my answer! ;)

Comment: Now it gives me another error
`Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim xRng As Range

Set xRng = Selection

If Me.CheckBox1_Click.Value Then

xRng.Interior.Color = vbGreen

Else

xRng.Interior.Color = xlNone

End If

End Sub`
The error is 'Expected Function or Variable' for .CheckBox1_Click

Comment: @Pooja : You used `Me.CheckBox1_Click.Value` **in your test** `If Me.CheckBox1_Click.Value Then`, you forgot to **get rid of the `_Click`** when copying! ;) Take a closer look at my answer, it should be `If Me.CheckBox1.Value Then` ;)

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry! My bad. But, now I changed it and getting the error 'method or data member not found' on .CheckBox1

Comment: @Pooja : If you use `Me.CheckBox1.Value` is the code in the sheet's module? If not, try to move it there or try the 1st part of my answer.

Comment: @Pooja : Try the edit! It's working smoothly for me! ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Now I am able to run the macro using Ralph's code

Comment: @Pooja : You are welcome, you can upvote as many posts as you want so don't hesitate! ;) But accept Ralph's one! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like follows

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Selection.Interior.Color = IIf(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("CheckBox1").Value = xlOn, vbGreen, 16777215)

End Sub
```

Comment: @Pooja, did you try this solution?

Comment: I just tried this code. It gives me the error 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: then either it's not a _Form_ checkbox (but rather an _ActiveX_ one), or it's not called "CheckBox1". Please check it out and let me know

Comment: I am sure about it being a form control. And, when I inserted the checkbox its name was 'Check Box 1'. I edited its name to 'CheckBox1' which we are using to write the code.

Comment: what you depicted is precisely my testing enevironment. try selecting your checkbox (right click on it), type in Immediate Window `?typename(selection)`, press return and see the returned value

Comment: When I right click on the checkbox, I cannot find any immediate window where I can type in! The right click just opens up the cut, copy, paste, format control, etc. drop down!

Comment: you must open your VBA IDE, and pop Immediate Window out by clicking CTRL+G..  And.... what's that "dropdown" about?

Comment: The returned value is CheckBox

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Now I am able to run the macro using Ralph's code