# Excel VBA Option Button Run Time Error 438 on New Machine

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that worked on my old work machine and confirmed still works on other work machines but doesn't work on a newly provided work computer.  Code appears to bomb when I reference the option button but works fine for all the rest of the code.  For instance this line:

```
Sub test()

    Sheets("Sheet1").OptionButton1.value = "False"

End Sub
```

Generates this error message:
Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I have verified the following:

- I am working off of the same version of Microsoft Excel as before
- The same references are included as before
- I am using Form controls, not ActiveX controls
- I get the same error even if I alter the code to : ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOff

Comment: If you are using Form controls, your syntax is wrong - that's how you refer to ActiveX controls.

Comment: If that's a form control then you might be interested in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811509/object-required-error-when-trying-to-refer-to-checkbox-in-worksheet/42811946#42811946

Comment: It is an ActiveX control.  After toying around some I realized that I can no longer insert any ActiveX controlls into my workbooks.  I ran across the following:

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025036/-cannot-insert-object-error-in-an-activex-custom-office-solution-after-you-install-the-ms14-082-security-update

Comment: But I am hoping to find an alternate fix as I don't have the permissions to install updates and IT who does have permissions is not responding to requests.