# Email based on checkbox - If function

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, outlook

I'm trying to send an automated mail based on whether a checkbox is checked.

The code works perfectly without the `If` function. But with it, I get:

> Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

I'd rather keep the `If` function so the mail only gets sent by checking the box. **Without the `If` function, the mail gets sent when unchecking as well.**

```
Sub Checkbox1_Click()
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim Mail As Object
    Dim subject_ As String
    Dim body_ As String
    subject_ = "Something"
    body_ = "Something else"
    If Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mail = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With Mail
            .Subject = subject_
            .Body = body_
            .To = "email"
            .CC = "otheremail"
            .Importance = 2
            .Send
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: Then Sheets("Sheet1") does not contain attribute `CheckBox1`. You should surely look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741836/checking-if-a-worksheet-based-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: Check this answer as well for checkbox condition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991308/how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-an-if-then-statement-in-excel-vba-2010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use checkboxes in an IF-THEN statement in Excel VBA 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991308/how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-an-if-then-statement-in-excel-vba-2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the ActiveSheet.OLEObjects ("CheckBox1"). Object.Value> 0 as condition to check it.
For more information, please see the following links:

[Using Control Names with the Shapes and OLEObjects Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741836/checking-if-a-worksheet-based-checkbox-is-checked)

[Checking if a worksheet-based checkbox is checked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/controls-dialogboxes-forms/using-activex-controls-on-sheets)